# How do you play Math Busters on the Commodore 64?

Tags: commodore-64, math-busters

Recently got the old Commodore out of my parents attic. Trying a game I vaguely remember called Math Busters by Spinnaker Software.

I don't have the manual and I can't figure out how to do  anything except jump and swim.  I can grab numbers and make equations, but they don't do anything and there is some sort of alien in a cave and a number machine with pipes on it and a dog I can jump on, but beyond that I'm lost.  Please help me reclaim this lost piece of my childhood so I can pass it to my wee boy Phillip.

Answer (score 2):

You have to collect numbers and operation symbols to make an equation who's answer matches the number on the monster's belly.

For the life of me, though, I can't remember what you do next to capture the monster.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got the equation result on the belly of the monster you're targeting you go up and vapourize them with whatever button makes you do the "pointing gun" pose while standing close to them and facing in their direction (but not directly in front of them). You then have to run left out of the cave and switch on the vacuum machine as the vapour emerges. It's all about timing. For the record there's a bell you can ring which will scramble the monsters or the numbers outside (can't remember which) but you have a limited number of times you can do that.
The dial indicates the total sum of monsters values you have sucked up. If it goes too great a positive or negative value it apparently explodes (I never succeeded in doing this, nor did I ever finish - always ran out of numbers).
I'd love to see the end of this game. Stick it up on youtube if you get a chance.